# Weird string appends on printf

Tags: c, string

I wrote a simple program to toggle string, I tried in my computer and IDEOne, I am receiving a weird string appended to the output. Am I missing something?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char input[100], output[100];
    int length;
    scanf("%s", input);

    length = sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]);

    for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (input[i] >= 97 && input[i] <= 122) {
            output[i] = input[i] - 32;
        } else if (input[i] >= 65 && input[i] <= 90) {
            output[i] = input[i] + 32;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Link to IDEOne - [`https://ideone.com/NFlDJK`](https://ideone.com/NFlDJK)

Comment: Trivia: What should come in the end of every C string? Really, you seem to even know that.

Comment: A character string has to be null terminated in c and c++.

Comment: Valid input characters are 99 characters. If it is over, the buffer overflows. try `scanf("%s", input);` --> `scanf("%99s", input);`

Comment: Keep in mind, if the input contains characters you choose to not copy to the output, you never assign a value to the matching index in the output string. This leaves your output containing uninitialized characters which will cause undefined behavior when you attempt to display it.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but instead of hard-coding magic numbers that restrict you to ASCII, use `isprint`, `toupper`, and `tolower`.

Comment: FYI, the correct way to find the length of a string is to use the strlen() function.  I noted the initialization of the `int length` variable, but it wasn't used anywhere.  I assumed that was because it wasn't giving you what you expected.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check  the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input/format specifier, always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer so no buffer overrun can occur.  Such buffer overrun is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when not going to use the parameters for `main()`, then use the `int main( void )` signature.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 100.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: The variable `length` is being set, but never used.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers--replace with char literals

Answer (score 2):

`%s` expects a null terminated string as an argument. You have to append a `'\0'` character at the end of `output`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't terminate your `output`, i.e. you do not write the final `\0`-character that marks the end of a string. Hence, `printf`, which expects a 0-terminated string, probably prints some garbage. A simple solution would be to define `output` as

```
char output[100] = { 0 };
```

Thereby, `output` will be filled with `\0` and anything you write in before will find some end then.

As pointed out in the comments, there are some more issues in the code which may lead to undefined behaviour or unexpected results.

First, you'll get a buffer overflow if you enter more than 99 characters (then yielding undefined behaviour). You could avoid this by using `scanf("%99s", input)`.

Second, you may get an unexpectedly short result if your input contains some characters not triggering your toggle-expression. In your code, `output` would contain garbage at the relevant position; in the `output = { 0 }`-variant, the result would "end" at this point. Hence, an input like `"abc1234DEF"` might yield `"ABC?@:-def"`or `"ABC"`, respectively. Add an `else { output[i]=input[i]; }` to overcome this.

Third, `length = sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0])` will always return `100`, regardless of the actual number of characters entered. Note that `sizeof(input)` will be `100` and `sizeof(input[0])` will `1` as compile time constants. To get the "length" of the string in terms of number of characters entered use `strlen(input)`.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char input[100], output[100] = { 0 };
    scanf("%99s", input);

    size_t length = strlen(input);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (input[i] >= 97 && input[i] <= 122) {
            output[i] = input[i] - 32;
        } else if (input[i] >= 65 && input[i] <= 90) {
            output[i] = input[i] + 32;
        }
        else {
            output[i] = input[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup, but
In the example of OP's ideone, a buffer overflow occurs at the input part. So, you need to fix it first.

Comment: Note that if the input contains anything that isn't a upper or lower case letter (a number or punctuation for example) then the output has gaps which are not overwritten. While this solution does improve significantly over the initial example (at least it's much less likely to have undefined behavior) it will still not give the result OP seems to be attempting to achieve.

Comment: @François Andrieux: right, though OP's sample did not contain such input. Anyway, it's necessary to consider such cases.

Comment: +1 I like your answer. In addition to avoiding magic numbers, `input[i] >= 97 && input[i] <= 122` , `32`... depends on the sequence of character codes.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to the question is:

the output[] array must be NUL (0x00) terminated.
The '%s" format specifier in the call to `printf()` does not stop outputting bytes until it encounters a NUL.

Since the posted code failed to set the needed NUL byte, the "%s" will keep outputting bytes until it happens upon some random NUL byte.
This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

You can fix the problem by:
after the `for()` code block and before the `printf()` statement, insert the statement:

```
output[i] = '\0';
```

Answer (score -2):

After your loop i is one more i.e you just have to put

Output[i]='\0';

And its done

Comment: Adds nothing not already covered by earlier answers. Downvote because this answer makes no attempt to explain anything.

Comment: I haven't downvote. but `i` undeclared at after for-loop.

Comment: thanks  -user4581301 to let me know that i have also to explain sorry for my answer as i use stackoverflow very less so i am not aware of how to answer these questions...